# When it is absolutely necessary to use the targetEntity attribut in JPA and when not?

Tags: java, jpa

I have a important question. When it is absolutely necessary to use the targetEntity attribute in a OneToMany- or in a ManyToOne relationsship in JPA? And when it can leave out?

Answer (score 6):

It's necessary when you're using raw types (but you should never us them): `Set` instead of `Set<Foo>`, or when the generic type of the collection is an interface or a base class, instead of the precise entity itself. In 99.9% of the cases, `targetEntity` is thus not necessary.

Comment: Have i this understood in right way? If "Set<Foo>" was set, no targetEntity muste be used (also Foo is an interface or a base class) but if "Set" is used, the targetentity attribut muste be set?

Comment: If you have a Set<Foo> and Foo is an entity, JPA knows the target entity from the type of the field: Set<Foo> implies that the target entity is Foo. If you just have Set, JPA can't imply anything. And if you have Set<SomeInterface> but actually want the set to be populated with Foos (where Foo implements SomeInterface), then you also have to specify the target entity to JPA.